# Forge Viewer - how to edit old markups?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are loading old markups into view via the `loadMarkups` method on the `Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore` extension, but we are struggling to find a way to enable editing of these markups. When they load they are just static, and the user cannot select them to move them or delete them.

Any pointers as to how this can be done is much appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically re-create the markups so that they are editable:

```
var arrow = new Autodesk.Extensions.Markup.Core.CreateArrow(markupExt, id, head, , style);
arrow.execute()
```

And access the markup objects to get their details for reconstruction via `markupExt.markups`:

```
markupExt.markups[0]
/*
head: LMV../thirdparty/three.js/three.js.THREE.Vector3 {x: 284.1781874039939, y: -321.0445468509985, z: 0}
highlightColor: "#0696D7"
highlighted: false
id: 1
minHeight: -10000
minWidth: -10000
position: {x: 55.29953917050693, y: -313.36405529953913}
rotation: 0.03354445956167922
selected: false
shape: g
size: {x: 458.0149585664656, y: 9.216589861751004}
style: {stroke-width: 3.072196620583668, stroke-color: "#ff0000", stroke-opacity: 1, fill-color: "#ff0000", fill-opacity: 1}
tail: LMV../thirdparty/three.js/three.js.THREE.Vector3 {x: -173.57910906298002, y: -305.68356374807985, z: 0}
*/
```

Comment: Where can I see which parameters I need to call e.g. CreateArrow? - I can't find the source code or any documentation on it. It sounds like I should not use the markupExt.generateData() method to get the markup data for storage if that means they won't be editable. So I need to figure out what to store instead

Comment: Unfortunately that bit of the code is not yet documented but you can pretty much tell what each arg is for by their names - will let you know once the doc's available

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by simply calling enterEditMode() with the LayerId i saved along with the generated SVG data in my database, like so:

```
markupsCoreExtension.enterEditMode(LayerID)
```

This enabled editing of saved markups for me. It doesn't work if you've implemented your own custom tool (type) however.